# How do I focus on the next field by testing event.which == 13 without leaving a trailing \n in the current field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

```
$("#title").keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which == 13){
        $("#nextField").focus();
    }
});
```

Q: How do I focus on `#details` with-out leaving a trailing `\n` in `#title`'s value?

Failed attempt:

```
$("#title").keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which == 13){
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\n/g,""));
        $("#nextField").focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: what kind of field is `#title`?

Comment: Are you trying to keep the newline or remove it?  Your code looks like it is trying to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is event.preventDefault();

```
$("#title").keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which == 13){
        $("#details").focus();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: @codethis That's what I meant; I was thinking of the wrong framework :)  I'm glad I was able to pop over and check the api before I confused anyone.

Comment: @Babiker You can see it in use on the example on keypress's page (where they are filtering out the enter key, as you are!) http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: @NickAldwin, @codethis - What's wrong the returning false? It worked fine?

Comment: Please use `event.preventDefault();` instead. In most of the cases `return false` does more than you actually want (prevent default, suppress immediate propagation, suppress propagation).

Comment: @Babiker It prevents chaining -- jQuery calls should generally return the jQuery object so that you can do `$("#something").onefunc().anotherfunc().another()` and so on.

Comment: @NickAldwin It shouldn't prevent chaining.  The keypress() (or any bind shorthand) methods are attaching handler functions and the handlers execute asynchronously.

Comment: My mistake.  Listen to Marcel Jackwerth.